# Problema al cargar tablas a la base de datos del hosting

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, hosting

tengo el inconveniente que al querer cargar el Backup de tablas en la base de datos del Hosting me saltan muchos errores, según el Hosting era un problema por un documento corrupto, pero al reiterar varias veces el Backup de las tablas y no funcionar no se como solucionarlo, adjunto errores de manera textual, desde ya gracias:

```
Se encontraron 22 errores durante el análisis.

Se esperaba el nombre de la variable. (near " " at position 26)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 79)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 157)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 163)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 174)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 184)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 192)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 204)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 255)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 261)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 272)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 282)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 290)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 946)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 952)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 963)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 973)
Caracter inesperado. (near "\" at position 981)
Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "br" at position 1)
Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "b" at position 8)
Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "Fatal" at position 10)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "error" at position 16)
```

consulta SQL:

> <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Export::exportDatabase() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Controllers\ExportController.php on line 549 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php:717 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Controllers\ExportController.php(549): PhpMyAdmin\Export->exportDatabase('prestashop', Array, NULL, Array, Array, Object(PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportSql), '\n', 'index.php?route...', 'database', false, false, false, false, Array, '') #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Routing.php(187): PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\ExportController->index(Array) #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute('/export', Object(FastRoute\Dispatcher\GroupCountBased), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php</b> on line <b>717</b><br />;

Comment: Como estas cargando el Back Up ?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y poner un fragmento del backup (si es posible). Muchas veces pasa que el contenido generado por, digamos, MySQL workbench no siempre es bien recibido por phpmyadmin, etc.

Comment: @MateoGuio Entro a la base de datos del hosting creada, me redirecciona a phpMyAdmin y dentro del mismo importo el archivo .sql generado previamente

Comment: Mucho me temo que lo que el OP denomina "Consulta SQL" es un archivo exportado de phpMyAdmin que el OP creía que se estaba descargando bien, cuando lo que ocurria era un error de exportación. Y ahora, al intentar cargarlo como si fuera un SQL válido le da esos errores.  En otras palabras, no hizo correctamente el backup y ahora solo tiene un archivo con errores de exportación que intenta importar y le da errores, claro.  Espero equivocarme por su bien.

Comment: Abre tu archivo .sql con un editor de codigo(Que te muestre el numero de la linea) y revisa las lineas que te indica donde hay error. O puedes tomarle pantallazo y editar tu rpegunta :)

Comment: @masterguru Cabe destacar que yo utilice xampp y la web es generada con prestashop, por lo que si bien entiendo a lo que te referis no se en que momento dado puede haber pasado esto y como tratar de solucionarlo

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por responder... No utilice MySQL workbench, utilice XAMMP para una pagina creada con prestashop, disculpa mi ignorancia.

Comment: @IvanG ¿El archivo que intentas importar es lo que aparece en la pregunta debajo de **Consulta SQL**?  Si es así, léetelo bien y veras que se ha generado con phpMyAdmin (desconozco como trabaja xampp, pero quizas usa funciones de phpMyAdmin para la exportación de bases de datos), Si la respuesta es **sí** entonces ese archivo no te sirve de nada y debes buscar copias de seguridad más antiguas que esten bien para importarlas, no se puede arreglar de otra forma a menos que no te haga falta recuperarlo y puedas continuar con tu base de datos actual y exportarla de nuevo para tener backup de hoy

Comment: @masterguru Perfecta tu explicación, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Alfabravo lo del error no lo puse así en mi edición de antes porque entonces no se verian los `<br>` que aparecian allí y que aparecen en el error despues: `Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "br" at position 1). Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "b" at position 8) Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "Fatal" at position 10)`... pero bueno, ahora ya da igual, ya lo ha entendido

Comment: @Alfabravo Arreglado, lo he forzado escapando esos caracteres en una nueva edición

Comment: @masterguru Gracias!! Es el primer post que realizo a modo de consulta, si me dijeras como puedo subir tu "reputacion" o algo por el estilo lo haria con gusto, saludos

Comment: @IvanG Te agradezco tu intención pero no te preocupes, me gusta más ayudar y superar retos y aprender sobre la marcha que ganar reputación, aunque tampoco la desprecio cuando me la dan, claro. En tu caso no puedo darte una respuesta porque no es un problema de programación en sí, es un error que dificilmente se puede repetir y no vale la pena redactar una respuesta. Ya lo has entendido y con eso me doy por satisfecho :-)  Saludos!